# Java Optional and orElse

Tags: java, option-type

I'm new to the Java optionals but I see this code written by another developer and I don't get it:

```
String t = null;
Optional.ofNullable("notnull")
    .orElse(
        Optional.ofNullable(t).orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("MyException"))
    );
```

Why does this code throw the exception? Why does it even go to the "orElse" branch?

Is this because of some weird execution order? So the first optional's value is not set before the orElse branch is evaluated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `orElse` stream is never invoked but the method itself is executed. This means that the method parameter is passed to it as well. So the part `Optional.ofNullable(t).orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("MyException"))` is being called regardless of the value passed to the first `Optional.ofNullable` call.

If you don't want this to happen you will need to pass a `Supplier` like this:

```java
String t = null;
Optional.ofNullable("notnull")
    .orElseGet(
        () -> Optional.ofNullable(t).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("MyException"))
    );
```

The supplier is only invoked when the `orElseGet` stream is invoked.
Note that you'll need a `RuntimeException` instead of a checked exception in order to be able to break from the supplier.

Comment: thanks, good explanation

Answer (score 6):

That's because the code inside **[`orElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-)** will be always evaluated. In other words it will be executed even if you specify a non-empty [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), so that's why the `Exception` will be thrown.

If you check the `orElse()` section of **[Java Optional – orElse() vs orElseGet()](https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional-or-else-vs-or-else-get#orElse)** article, you can see that in their example, where it says:

> We can easily infer that the parameter of orElse() is evaluated even when having a non-empty Optional.

Answer (score 3):

What you wrote is the same like this:

```
String t = null;
String myException = Optional.ofNullable(t).orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("MyException"));
Optional.ofNullable("notnull").orElse(myException);
```

Part `orElse` of `Optional` is evaluated before you know is your value null or not.If you want `"Lazy"` evaluation consider `orElseGet` method.

Answer (score 3):

I really wonder why this code has been written in this fashion. It seems that it needed to trigger an exception with an explicit NULL value added to the optional.

As already said when using `orElse()` instead of `orElseGet()` the method is evaluated no matter the value of T (e.g `Optional<T>`).

I would use for a better fashion and undertanding:

```
String value = "notnull"; // could be null
Optional.ofNullable(value)
    .orElseThrow(MyException::new);
```

In case the value is NULL the exception is triggered.

**Note : you can use method references to invoke exceptions**

Answer (score 3):

There are few things you should note about [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

1. If it is known the value being wrapped is null or not, use [Optional.of()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#of) or [Optional.empty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#empty--). If not sure, (for example value is a variable you got from somewhere else) use [Optional.ofNullable()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-)
2. There is an important difference between [Optional.orElse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) and [Optional.orElseGet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-).

   1. `orElse` takes an already computed value, if an expression is provided, it is executed and evaluated right then and there. *This is happening in the code in question*. Hence this else variant should be used for already available values or primitives.
   2. `orElseGet` takes a Supplier function that is only run when the optional chain is evaluated and alternative value is requested. This should be used where the alternative value is expensive to produce or compute.

   ```
   // Fine
   Optional<String> name = Optional.of(someValue).orElse("defaultName");

   // But this:
   Optional<String> name = Optional.of(someValue).orElse(db.queryName());

   // Is better written as following, as it saves you from an expensive operation
   Optional<String> name = Optional.of(someValue).orElseGet(() -> db.queryName());
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Issue is in order of execution.
It is trying to compute value for .orElse(...) and throws MyException on the .orElseThrow.

In other words if t is not null execution flow is following:

1) compute value of

```
Optional.ofNullable(t).orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("MyException"))
```

2) use value from (1) in

```
Optional.ofNullable("notnull").orElse(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

The result is expected because in Java before invoking a method that takes a parameter, the thing that the JVM does before is evaluating the parameter value.
And that is the parameter value of the `.orElse()` invocation :

```
Optional.ofNullable(t).orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("MyException"))
```

Since `t` refers to `null`, the exception throw is expected.